# mmcblk0 missing in dev

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu but have been mounting images on sd cards to use in kiosks and partitioning drives using `fdisk/dev/mmcblk0` then going from there.
I mounted an image the other day and when I went to partition the drive it said
 `fdisk/dev/mmcblk0: command not found`.
So I used another image and tried again but to no avail. I am using Win32 Disk Imager to mount like I always have but for some reason `mmcblk0` is not showing up in the `dev` file. I apologize if this has been asked before but I have not seen it anywhere.

Comment: Memory cards aren't always `mmcblk0` device, sometimes they're recognized simply as another `sdb` device.  Check `lsblk` output, and try to find one that matches the size of the memory card.

Comment: I notice that the command as you have entered it into your question is not quite correct - there should be a space between `fdisk` and `/`, so the command should look like `fdisk /dev/mmcblk0`